# Linux dhcp server for wlan/wired

Tags: linux, dhcp-server

I want to configure my dhcp server on a debian router which uses different ip range based on the type of user connection; wlan or wired. The wlan is set in bridge mode!
Since it is a public net I don't know client MAC address in advance. Any chance to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use two different vlans for wireless and wired, and setup a DHCP pool for each with different subnets